# How to know what static libraries have been linked with an iOS build?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, build

Is there a way to find out what framework / static libraries have been linked with an iOS build (ipa file) assuming you have no access to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, because symbols from static libraries are *copied* into your binary without any reference to the original static library. Maybe there's some magic, but I'm not aware of it.

But you can use `nm` for example to list symbols in your executable and then guess from where they came from.